# Formal proof by natural deduction

Tags: propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

The question asked for a formal proof, by natural deduction, of:

⊢N ( A ∧ B ) ↔ ¬( A → ¬B)

I can use the rules of system N and the rule 'repetitive inward' (RI)

[Rules of System N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wotR4.jpg)

I started backwards by establishing that I have to prove

Box 1: ( A ∧ B )  ⊢ ¬( A → ¬B) and

Box 2:  ¬( A → ¬B) ⊢ ( A ∧ B ) so that I can apply the (↔ I) rule.

Box 1:

A --- Assumption

B --- Assumption

A ∧ B -- ( ∧I)

Is this correct?

Also, can someone help me in proving box 2 by natural deduction? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: How is 'System N' defined? Please add that to your post.  But no, your proof for 'Box 1' cannot possibly be correct, given that you have to end up with $\neg ( A \to \neg B)$, but instead you end with $A \land B$

Comment: I have added a link to the rules. Oh yes I realised my mistake!

Comment: Generally, how do you know which rules to apply? Do you kind of work backwards to see what you need to get? If not, I am totally lost as to how to start proving.

Comment: Doing proofs is a bit like playing chess: it's easy to learn the rules that tell you what moves you can make... but it's a lot harder to know what moves to actually make at what time. And, like chess, the only way to get good at this is practice. That said, yes, there are some general strategies that Cn improve your chances of success .... and yes, often it is working backward that provides the basic set-up for your proofs. For example. To prove $\neg (A \to \neg B)$, you probably have to use $\neg $ Intro: assume $A \to \neg B$, and show that that leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @Djy Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

> I started backwards by establishing that I have to prove
>
> Box 1: ( A ∧ B ) ⊢ ¬( A → ¬B) and
>
> Box 2: ¬( A → ¬B) ⊢ ( A ∧ B ) so that I can apply the (↔ I) rule.

Indeed.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l|}\hline #1\\\hline#2\\\hline \end{array}}
\fitch{}{\fitch{A\wedge B}{~~\vdots\\\neg (A\to\neg B)}\\\fitch{\neg(A\to\neg B)}{~~\vdots\\A\wedge B}\\(A\wedge B)\leftrightarrow\neg(A\to\neg B)}$$

> Box 1:
>
> A --- Assumption
>
> B --- Assumption
>
> A ∧ B -- ( ∧I)
>
> Is this correct?

No.  You have *assumed* $A\wedge B$.  From this you may derive $A$ and $B$ using the $\wedge$ elimination rules.  Then you seek to derive from that $\neg(A\to\neg B)$.  For that use the $\neg$ Introduction rule, which requires assuming $A\to\neg B$.

Oh, but look, you may derive $A$ from $A\wedge B$, and assumed $A\to\neg B$, so now you may use the $\to$ elimination rule to derive $\neg B$.  And you may also derive $B$ from $A\wedge B$ too.

I'll through a tip for the second box in too.  You are going to want to *introduce* that $\wedge$.  To derive the $A$ and $B$ use the $\neg$ *elimination* rule (so assume their negations, aiming to derive contraditions).

But *what* are you going to contradict in each box?

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{A\wedge B}{\fitch{A\to\neg B}{A\hspace{16ex}\wedge\mathsf E\\\neg B\hspace{14ex}\to\mathsf E\\B\hspace{16ex}\wedge\mathsf E}\\\neg (A\to\neg B)\hspace{10ex}\neg~\mathsf I}\\\fitch{\neg(A\to\neg B)}{\fitch{\neg A}{\vdots}\\A\\\fitch{\neg B}{\vdots}\\B\\A\wedge B}\\(A\wedge B)\leftrightarrow\neg(A\to\neg B)\hspace{2ex}\leftrightarrow\mathsf I}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this, i understand it a lot better! However, im still stuck at deriving A in box 2, as to how i can use the assumption ¬( A → ¬B) to derive contradictions. Do you have any further hint for this?

Comment: That format is nice, I think I know how to prove the second box in normal natural deduction, but I'm not sure about system N

Comment: @Djy Is there $\bot \text{Intro}$ and $\bot \text{Elim}$ in system N $?$

Comment: No, there isn't!

Comment: @Djy $\neg(A\to\neg B)$ is an active assumption so may be reiteratted as needed.  So *in each box* you must seek to derive $A\to\neg B$. Do so by assuming $A$, aiming to derive $\neg B$.

Comment: @Manx In that system there is no $⊥$ symbol to introduce. Rather, the *negation introduction* and *elimination* rules merely require being able to derive two contradictory statements from the assumption.  (Note: this system's negation elimination rule is Reductio Ad Absurdum (RAA).) 
$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l|}\hline#1\\\hline#2\\\hline\end{array}}\tiny\fitch{}{\fitch{~P\qquad}{~~\vdots\\~~Q\\\neg Q}\\\neg P\qquad(\neg\mathsf I)}\quad\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg P\qquad}{~~\vdots\\~~Q\\\neg Q}\\~~ P\qquad(\neg\mathsf E)}$$

Comment: Likewise, the *principle of explosion* isn't a fundamental rule, but may be derived. When you have contradictory statements, you may use them to derive anything. $$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l|}\hline#1\\\hline#2\\\hline\end{array}}\tiny\fitch{~~~P\\\neg P}{\fitch{\neg Q}{~~P\qquad(\mathsf{RI})\\\neg P\qquad(\mathsf{RI})}\\~~Q\qquad(\neg\mathsf E)}$$ What @Djy refers to as the Repetitive Inward rule appears to be the Rule of Reiteration (or Restatement): that if a statement *has been* derived or assumed in a box containing the current box, then it can be restated into the current box.